# File won't save as JavaScript extension in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, notepad++, file-extension

I am trying to use an external JavaScript file in my HTML as follows:

`<script src='MyScript.js'></script>`

The issue is, I am getting the following error in the Web console:

`Loading failed for the <script> with source "file:///F:/GIS%20Assessment%202/MyScript.js".`

I have realised that MyScript is not saved as having the JavaScript extension, in my documents it says it's a "File" rather than a JavaScript file. I have tried changing the language to JavaScript and saving as a JavaScript file as soon as I save it in my folder it just converts to a generic file!

What do I do? How do I fix this and save my scripts as JavaScript?

Comment: Format code by prefixing it with 4 spaces, or enclosing it in backticks.

Comment: How are you saving the file? Are you sure you're referencing it correctly - is it in the correct directory?

Comment: if you use window try enabling the option to show filename extensions and make sure it's `.js`

Comment: You should be using a web server instead of trying to do it over the `file:///` scheme.

Comment: Have you check if you have permissions? Maybe check if you have access to do something in the folder like saving a regular file from notepad

Comment: @Crowcoder an overkill. Based on the directory name, seems like an assignment from school. I've never really had to set up a whole server to submit mine - a local HTML + JS + CSS was enough back in my (not so distant) days.

Comment: @VLAZ a whole server is as simple as `http-server`.

Comment: @Crowcoder still an overkill for a school assignment. Heck, if I do a quick HTML + JS sample to test something *now* I wouldn't set up a web server and just rely on reading the files locally. Not sure why you feel otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

To force it to have the extension, simply enclose the filename (with the extension) in quotes.

> "MyScript.js"

Comment: "*This isn't really a programming question*" questions about tools used by programmers (especially when used *for programming*) are on topic. If Notepad++ is saving incorrectly, then that's an SO question, although it *can* also be asked over at SU.

Comment: I find questions like this one a gray area (which is why I answered it instead of voting to close).  I tend to agree with you (hence the upvote on the comment), but have found that there is often a hurry to close questions like these that don't fit into neat "programming" boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I found it worked when I typed the file extension in capitals when saving the file: "myfile.JS" instead of "myfile.js"